# Using return status in Postgresql function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.5

So I have a sybase stored procedure and I'm moving it in Postgres 9.5 but I can't seem to make a portion of it working. In the procedure there is an if clause that at the end has return 0 like below:
In Sybase:

```
if @param = true begin
 select col1, col2
 from table
 where <condition>
return 0
end
```

How can I use the return status in a Postgres function using plpgsql language?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PostgreSQL functions has not any similar to return status. Any function should to return data or should to raise a exception. The return status is not necessary. The programming in plpgsql is similar to Oracle's PL/SQL or IBM's DB2. Sybase, T-SQL is very far from PLpgSQL - good start is reading a manual, because lot of things are different - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html

your code in PLpgSQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(param boolean)
RETURNS SETOF tablename AS $$
BEGIN
  IF param THEN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM tablename
      WHERE ..
  ELSE
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'xxxx';
  END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

No exception - it is analogy return status 0, exception -- some nonzero return status.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was thinking of RAISE EXCEPTION but was not sure. It works for what I have.